# Account structure with multiple nested and recursive parent / child hierarchy

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

This is my very first question asked (ever). So, please be patient while I try to explain my problem.

I have a table as follows which is giving me the hierarchy structure for some account:

```
declare @AccountDefinitions table
    (
     AccountID int identity(1, 1)
                   primary key
                   not null,
     AccountNumber nvarchar(11) not null,
     AccountType nvarchar(1) not null,
     SumSign1 smallint,
     SumAccount1 nvarchar(11),
     SumSign2 smallint,
     SumAccount2 nvarchar(11),
     SumSign3 smallint,
     SumAccount3 nvarchar(11)
    )
```

If an account is summed up (added to another acount) then the parent account is in SumAccount1. So, SumAccount1 can be found in AccountNumber again. That's the ordinary parent / child hierarchy which could be easily solved with a CTE as described in multiple solutions.
Yet, there are two more parent columns with the names SumAccount2 and SumAccount3. This means that an account may have up to three parents. But sometimes there are only two parents or no parents. In such cases SumAccount3 (and / or the others) would be NULL.

Basically, now I would need a nested CTE to deal with these multiple possible parents which may lead to multiple different paths. If an account has three parents and each of these have another three parents then there are already nine different paths this account could be potentially added up to.

Here is some test data to play around with:

```
insert  into @AccountDefinitions
        (AccountNumber, AccountType, SumSign1, SumAccount1, SumSign2,
         SumAccount2, SumSign3, SumAccount3)
values  (N'K07_005', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_010', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_010A', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_020', N'R', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_020A', N'R', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_020AA', N'R', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_021', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_022', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_025', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_025A', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_035', N'U', 1, N'K07_060', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_060', N'U', 1, N'K07_930', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_090', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_091', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_091P', N'U', 0, null, 1, N'K07_O091', 0, null),
        (N'K07_092', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_095', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_096', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_100', N'U', 0, null, 1, N'K07_1000', 0, null),
        (N'K07_1000', N'I', 1, N'K07_O100', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_1010', N'I', 1, N'K07_100', 1, N'K07_101P', 1, N'K07_C130'),
        (N'K07_101P', N'U', 1, N'K07_O101', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_110', N'I', 1, N'K07_130', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_120', N'I', 1, N'K07_130', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_120P', N'U', 1, N'K07_O120', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_160', N'I', 1, N'K07_170', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_170', N'I', 1, N'K07_251', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_180', N'U', 1, N'K07_190', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_185', N'S', 1, N'K07_190', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_190', N'S', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_200', N'I', 1, N'K07_2000', 1, N'K07_250', 0, null),
        (N'K07_2000', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_201', N'I', 1, N'K07_C810', 1, N'K07_900', 1, N'K07_200'),
        (N'K07_202', N'I', 1, N'K07_202P', 1, N'K07_251', 0, null),
        (N'K07_202P', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_205', N'C', 1, N'K07_091P', -1, N'K07_251', 0, null),
        (N'K07_250', N'U', 1, N'K07_300', 1, N'K07_2500', 0, null),
        (N'K07_2500', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_251', N'I', 1, N'K07_301', 1, N'K07_251P', 0, null),
        (N'K07_251P', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_270', N'T', -1, N'K07_300', 1, N'K07_2700', 0, null),
        (N'K07_2700', N'T', 1, N'K07_O270', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_271', N'C', -1, N'K07_301', 1, N'K07_271P', 0, null),
        (N'K07_271P', N'T', 0, null, 1, N'K07_O271', 0, null),
        (N'K07_280', N'T', -1, N'K07_300', 1, N'K07_2800', 0, null),
        (N'K07_2800', N'T', 1, N'K07_O280', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_281', N'C', -1, N'K07_301', 1, N'K07_281P', 0, null),
        (N'K07_281P', N'T', 0, null, 1, N'K07_O281', 0, null),
        (N'K07_300', N'U', 1, N'K07_400', 1, N'K07_3000', 0, null),
        (N'K07_3000', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_301', N'I', 1, N'K07_401', 1, N'K07_301P', 0, null),
        (N'K07_301P', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_320', N'T', 1, N'K07_400', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_321', N'I', 1, N'K07_401', 1, N'K07_342', 0, null),
        (N'K07_322', N'I', 1, N'K07_401', 1, N'K07_342', 0, null),
        (N'K07_330', N'T', 1, N'K07_400', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_331', N'I', 1, N'K07_401', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_340', N'T', 1, N'K07_400', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_341', N'I', 1, N'K07_401', 1, N'K07_342', 0, null),
        (N'K07_342', N'C', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_350', N'T', 1, N'K07_400', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_351', N'C', 1, N'K07_401', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_400', N'U', 1, N'K07_600', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_401', N'C', 1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_510', 0, null),
        (N'K07_420', N'T', 1, N'K07_500', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_421', N'C', 1, N'K07_501', 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_430', N'T', 1, N'K07_500', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_431', N'C', 1, N'K07_501', 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_440', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_441', N'T', 1, N'K07_465', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_450', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_451', N'T', 1, N'K07_465', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_455', N'C', 1, N'K07_463', 1, N'K07_466', 0, null),
        (N'K07_456', N'U', 1, N'K07_465', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_457', N'C', 1, N'K07_463', 1, N'K07_466', 0, null),
        (N'K07_458', N'C', 1, N'K07_463', 1, N'K07_466', 0, null),
        (N'K07_459', N'C', 1, N'K07_463', 1, N'K07_466', 0, null),
        (N'K07_460', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_461', N'T', 1, N'K07_465', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_462', N'T', 1, N'K07_465', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_463', N'T', 1, N'K07_501', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_464', N'T', 1, N'K07_465', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_465', N'T', 1, N'K07_500', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_466', N'C', 0, null, 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_470', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_471', N'T', 1, N'K07_485', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_472', N'C', 1, N'K07_475', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_473', N'C', 1, N'K07_475', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_474', N'C', 1, N'K07_475', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_475', N'C', 1, N'K07_501', 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_476', N'C', 1, N'K07_475', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_480', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_481', N'T', 1, N'K07_485', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_482', N'T', 1, N'K07_485', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_483', N'T', 1, N'K07_485', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_484', N'T', 1, N'K07_485', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_485', N'T', 1, N'K07_500', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_488', N'T', 1, N'K07_500', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_489', N'C', 1, N'K07_501', 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_490', N'T', 1, N'K07_500', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_491', N'C', 1, N'K07_501', 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_492', N'C', 1, N'K07_501', 1, N'K07_502', 0, null),
        (N'K07_500', N'T', -1, N'K07_600', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_501', N'T', -1, N'K07_601', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_502', N'C', -1, N'K07_510', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_510', N'C', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_520', N'T', -1, N'K07_600', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_521', N'C', -1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_466', 0, null),
        (N'K07_522', N'C', -1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_466', 0, null),
        (N'K07_530', N'U', 1, N'K07_600', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_531', N'I', 1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_532', N'C', -1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_703', 1, N'K07_502'),
        (N'K07_533', N'I', 1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_540', N'U', 1, N'K07_600', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_541', N'I', 1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_551', N'I', 1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_561', N'C', -1, N'K07_601', -1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_571', N'I', 1, N'K07_601', 1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_581', N'C', -1, N'K07_601', -1, N'K07_591', 0, null),
        (N'K07_591', N'C', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_600', N'U', 1, N'K07_700', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_601', N'C', 1, N'K07_701', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_620', N'T', 1, N'K07_700', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_621', N'C', 1, N'K07_701', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_700', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_703', N'T', 1, N'K07_706', 1, N'K07_704', 0, null),
        (N'K07_704', N'T', 1, N'K07_707', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705', N'T', 1, N'K07_706', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705CO', N'T', 1, N'K07_705SU', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705GA', N'T', 1, N'K07_705SU', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705MS', N'T', 1, N'K07_705SU', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705OT', N'T', 1, N'K07_705SU', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705RD', N'T', 1, N'K07_705SU', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_705SU', N'T', 1, N'K07_707', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_706', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_707', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_710', N'U', 1, N'K07_760', 1, N'K07_7100', 1, N'K07_C050'),
        (N'K07_7100', N'U', 1, N'K07_O710', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_720', N'U', 1, N'K07_760', 1, N'K07_7200', 1, N'K07_C055'),
        (N'K07_7200', N'U', 1, N'K07_O720', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_7300', N'U', 1, N'K07_O730', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_7400', N'U', 1, N'K07_O740', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_7500', N'U', 1, N'K07_O750', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_760', N'U', 1, N'K07_910', 1, N'K07_7600', 1, N'K07_C075'),
        (N'K07_7600', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_800', N'U', 1, N'K07_810', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_800N', N'U', 1, N'K07_810N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_805', N'U', 1, N'K07_810', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_805N', N'U', 1, N'K07_810N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_810', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_810N', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_815', N'U', 1, N'K07_825', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_815N', N'U', 1, N'K07_825N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_820', N'U', 1, N'K07_825', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_820N', N'U', 1, N'K07_825N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_825', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_825N', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_830', N'U', 1, N'K07_840', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_830N', N'U', 1, N'K07_840N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_835', N'U', 1, N'K07_840', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_835N', N'U', 1, N'K07_840N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_840', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_840N', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_845', N'U', 1, N'K07_855', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_845N', N'U', 1, N'K07_855N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_850', N'U', 1, N'K07_855', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_850N', N'U', 1, N'K07_855N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_855', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_855N', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_860', N'U', 1, N'K07_870', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_860N', N'U', 1, N'K07_870N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_865', N'U', 1, N'K07_870', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_865N', N'U', 1, N'K07_870N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_870', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_870N', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_875', N'U', 1, N'K07_885', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_875N', N'U', 1, N'K07_885N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_880', N'U', 1, N'K07_885', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_880N', N'U', 1, N'K07_885N', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_885', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_885N', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_900', N'U', -1, N'K07_920', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_905', N'U', 1, N'K07_920', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_910', N'U', -1, N'K07_940', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_912', N'U', 1, N'K07_920', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_915', N'U', 1, N'K07_920', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_918', N'U', 1, N'K07_920', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_920', N'U', 1, N'K07_940', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_930', N'U', 1, N'K07_920', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_940', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C010', N'U', 1, N'K07_C045', 1, N'K07_C130', -1, N'K07_C050'),
        (N'K07_C015', N'U', 1, N'K07_C045', 1, N'K07_C135', -1, N'K07_C055'),
        (N'K07_C045', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, -1, N'K07_C075'),
        (N'K07_C050', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C055', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C060', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C065', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C070', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C075', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C100', N'U', 1, N'K07_C125', 1, N'K07_C130', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C105', N'U', 1, N'K07_C125', 1, N'K07_C135', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C125', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C130', N'U', 1, N'K07_C155', 1, N'K07_C630', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C135', N'U', 1, N'K07_C155', 1, N'K07_C635', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C155', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C400', N'U', 1, N'K07_C425', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C405', N'U', 1, N'K07_C425', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C425', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C430', N'U', 1, N'K07_C455', 1, N'K07_C580', 1, N'K07_C4300'),
        (N'K07_C4300', N'U', 1, N'K07_O430', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C435', N'U', 1, N'K07_C455', 1, N'K07_C585', 1, N'K07_C4350'),
        (N'K07_C4350', N'U', 1, N'K07_O435', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C4400', N'U', 1, N'K07_O440', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C4450', N'U', 1, N'K07_O445', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C4500', N'U', 1, N'K07_O450', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C455', N'U', 1, N'K07_C4550', 1, N'K07_C890', -1, N'K07_C810'),
        (N'K07_C4550', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C460', N'U', 1, N'K07_C485', -1, N'K07_C490', 1, N'K07_C580'),
        (N'K07_C465', N'U', 1, N'K07_C485', -1, N'K07_C495', 1, N'K07_C585'),
        (N'K07_C485', N'U', -1, N'K07_C515', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C490', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C495', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C500', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C505', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C510', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C515', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C520', N'U', 1, N'K07_C545', 1, N'K07_C490', 1, N'K07_C5200'),
        (N'K07_C5200', N'U', 1, N'K07_O520', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C525', N'U', 1, N'K07_C545', 1, N'K07_C495', 1, N'K07_C5250'),
        (N'K07_C5250', N'U', 1, N'K07_O525', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C5300', N'U', 1, N'K07_O530', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C5350', N'U', 1, N'K07_O535', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C5400', N'U', 1, N'K07_O540', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C545', N'U', 0, null, 1, N'K07_C515', 1, N'K07_C5450'),
        (N'K07_C5450', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C550', N'U', 1, N'K07_C575', 1, N'K07_C580', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C555', N'U', 1, N'K07_C575', 1, N'K07_C585', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C575', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C580', N'U', 1, N'K07_C599', 1, N'K07_C730', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C585', N'U', 1, N'K07_C599', 1, N'K07_C735', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C599', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C600', N'U', 1, N'K07_C625', 1, N'K07_C630', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C605', N'U', 1, N'K07_C625', 1, N'K07_C635', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C625', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C630', N'U', 1, N'K07_C655', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C635', N'U', 1, N'K07_C655', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C655', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C700', N'U', 1, N'K07_C725', 1, N'K07_C730', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C705', N'U', 1, N'K07_C725', 1, N'K07_C735', 0, null),
        (N'K07_C725', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C730', N'U', 1, N'K07_C755', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C735', N'U', 1, N'K07_C755', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C755', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C800', N'U', -1, N'K07_C890', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C810', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C830', N'U', -1, N'K07_C890', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C870', N'U', -1, N'K07_C890', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_C890', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I110', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I120', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I130', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I140', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I150', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I160', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I170', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I180', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I190', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I200', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I290', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I295', N'T', 1, N'K07_I300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I300', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I310', N'C', 1, N'K07_I400', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I320', N'C', 1, N'K07_I400', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_I400', N'C', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O091', N'U', -1, N'K07_O251', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O100', N'U', 1, N'K07_O200', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O101', N'U', 1, N'K07_O202', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O115', N'U', 1, N'K07_O200', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O116', N'U', 1, N'K07_O200', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O117', N'U', 1, N'K07_O200', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O118', N'U', 1, N'K07_O200', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O120', N'U', 1, N'K07_O202', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O200', N'U', 1, N'K07_O250', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O202', N'U', 1, N'K07_O251', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O250', N'U', 1, N'K07_O300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O251', N'U', 1, N'K07_O301', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O270', N'T', -1, N'K07_O300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O271', N'T', -1, N'K07_O301', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O280', N'T', -1, N'K07_O300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O281', N'T', -1, N'K07_O301', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O300', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O301', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O430', N'U', 1, N'K07_O455', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O435', N'U', 1, N'K07_O455', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O440', N'U', 1, N'K07_O455', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O445', N'U', 1, N'K07_O455', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O450', N'U', 1, N'K07_O455', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O455', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O520', N'U', 1, N'K07_O545', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O525', N'U', 1, N'K07_O545', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O530', N'U', 1, N'K07_O545', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O535', N'U', 1, N'K07_O545', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O540', N'U', 1, N'K07_O545', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O545', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O710', N'U', 1, N'K07_O760', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O720', N'U', 1, N'K07_O760', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O730', N'U', 1, N'K07_O760', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O740', N'U', 1, N'K07_O760', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O750', N'U', 1, N'K07_O760', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_O760', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P091', N'U', -1, N'K07_P251', 1, N'K07_O091', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P091US', N'U', -1, N'K07_P251US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P101', N'U', 1, N'K07_P1010', 1, N'K07_PP101', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P115', N'U', 1, N'K07_O115', 1, N'K07_P200', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P116', N'U', 1, N'K07_O116', 1, N'K07_P200', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P117', N'U', 1, N'K07_O117', 1, N'K07_P200', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P118', N'U', 1, N'K07_O118', 1, N'K07_P200', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P120', N'U', 1, N'K07_O120', 1, N'K07_P202', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P120US', N'U', 0, null, 1, N'K07_P202US', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P200', N'U', 1, N'K07_P250', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P202', N'U', 1, N'K07_P251', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P202US', N'U', 1, N'K07_P251US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P250', N'U', 1, N'K07_P300', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P251', N'U', 1, N'K07_P301', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P251US', N'U', 1, N'K07_P301US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P270', N'T', -1, N'K07_P300', 1, N'K07_O270', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P271', N'T', -1, N'K07_P301', 1, N'K07_O271', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P271US', N'T', -1, N'K07_P301US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P280', N'T', -1, N'K07_P300', 1, N'K07_O280', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P281', N'T', -1, N'K07_P301', 1, N'K07_O281', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P281US', N'T', -1, N'K07_P301US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P300', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P301', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P301US', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P430', N'U', 1, N'K07_O430', 1, N'K07_P455', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P435', N'U', 1, N'K07_O435', 1, N'K07_P455', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P440', N'U', 1, N'K07_O440', 1, N'K07_P455', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P445', N'U', 1, N'K07_O445', 1, N'K07_P455', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P450', N'U', 1, N'K07_O450', 1, N'K07_P455', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P455', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P489US', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P520', N'U', 1, N'K07_O520', 1, N'K07_P545', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P521US', N'T', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P525', N'U', 1, N'K07_O525', 1, N'K07_P545', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P530', N'U', 1, N'K07_O530', 1, N'K07_P545', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P535', N'U', 1, N'K07_O535', 1, N'K07_P545', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P540', N'U', 1, N'K07_O540', 1, N'K07_P545', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P545', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P710', N'U', 1, N'K07_O710', 1, N'K07_P760', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P710US', N'U', 1, N'K07_P760US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P720', N'U', 1, N'K07_O720', 1, N'K07_P760', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P720US', N'U', 1, N'K07_P760US', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P730', N'U', 1, N'K07_O730', 1, N'K07_P760', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P740', N'U', 1, N'K07_O740', 1, N'K07_P760', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P750', N'U', 1, N'K07_O750', 1, N'K07_P760', 0, null),
        (N'K07_P760', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_P760US', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_PA101', N'U', -1, N'K07_PP101', 0, null, 0, null),
        (N'K07_PP101', N'U', 0, null, 0, null, 0, null);
```

My attempt now was to get the nested hierarchy with multiple joins. But this doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
with    Hierarchy(AccountNumber, ParentsPaths)
          as (
              select    ad1.AccountNumber,
                        cast(N'' as nvarchar(max))
              from      @AccountDefinitions as ad1
              where     ad1.SumAccount1 is null
              union all
              select    ad2.AccountNumber,
                        cast(case when h.ParentsPaths = N''
                                  then (cast(ad2.AccountNumber as nvarchar(max)))
                                  else (h.ParentsPaths + '.'
                                        + cast(ad2.AccountNumber as nvarchar(max)))
                             end as nvarchar(max))
              from      @AccountDefinitions as ad2
              inner join Hierarchy as h
                        on h.AccountNumber = ad2.SumAccount1
                           or h.AccountNumber = ad2.SumAccount2
                           or h.AccountNumber = ad2.SumAccount3
              where     ad2.SumAccount1 is not null
             )
    select  *
    from    Hierarchy
    order by len(ParentsPaths) desc
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

In the end I would need to get a list of all accounts and all intermediary steps where they were added to, so that I can join the resulting table with all financial bookings and get all values summed up together.

Example: for K07_1000 there is only one possible path being K07_1000 adds to K07_O100, which adds up to K07_O200 and finally ends in K07_O250. In order to be able to join this, I would need the result:

```
Original | Mapped 
------------------- 
K07_1000 | K07_1000  <-- preserve the original posting
K07_1000 | K07_O100  <-- the one and only path
K07_1000 | K07_O200
K07_1000 | K07_O250
K07_1000 | K07_O300
```

If I join this table on the booking table then I would get for one booking to account K07_1000 four resulting bookings: the original and three more (which would add to the summed up parent accounts).

For account K07_1010 it would be more difficult as it can take four different paths.

```
Original | Mapped 
------------------- 
K07_1010 | K07_1010   <-- the original posting
K07_1010 | K07_100    <-- first possible path
K07_1010 | K07_1000
K07_1010 | K07_O100
K07_1010 | K07_O200
K07_1010 | K07_O250
K07_1010 | K07_O300
K07_1010 | K07_101P   <-- second possible path
K07_1010 | K07_O101
K07_1010 | K07_O202
K07_1010 | K07_O251
K07_1010 | K07_O301
K07_1010 | K07_C130   <-- third possible path
K07_1010 | K07_C155    <- third path with sub path 1
K07_1010 | K07_C630    <- third path with sub path 2
K07_1010 | K07_C655    <- third path with sub path 2
```

I hope this makes sense and someone can help.

Comment: Can you add output for example K07_1000 and K07_1010?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to add sample results. Sorry, I didn't think of that before. I changed the question to add the two samples you mentioned. Sure hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: 1. K07_1010 -> K07_C130 -> K07_C155 why this is not in your result?
2. K07_1010 -> K07_100 why this is not in result?
3. K07_1010 -> K07_101P -> K07_O202 -> K07_O251 -> K07_O301 also this is not in result.
4. K07_1010 -> K07_100 -> K07_1000 -> K07_O100 -> K07_O200 ->K07_O250 -> K07_O300 this also

Comment: I realized the missing paths you mentioned just shortly before your post and made the appropriate changes. Now, it should be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ralph, try this. I think it is working:

```
with    Hierarchy
          as (
              select    ad1.AccountNumber,
                        SumAccount1,
                        SumAccount2,
                        SumAccount3
              from      @AccountDefinitions as ad1

              union all

              select    h.AccountNumber,
                        ad2.SumAccount1,
                        ad2.SumAccount2,
                        ad2.SumAccount3
              from      @AccountDefinitions as ad2
              inner join Hierarchy as h
                        on h.SumAccount1 = ad2.AccountNumber
                        or h.SumAccount2 = ad2.AccountNumber
                        or h.SumAccount3 = ad2.AccountNumber
             ),

cter 
  as(
     SELECT AccountNumber, AccountNumber AS SumAccount FROM @AccountDefinitions

     UNION

     select  AccountNumber,
             SumAccount1 as SumAccount   
     from    Hierarchy
     where  SumAccount1 is not null

     union

     select  AccountNumber,
             SumAccount2 as SumAccount   
     from    Hierarchy
     where SumAccount2 is not null

     union

     select  AccountNumber,
             SumAccount3 as SumAccount   
     from    Hierarchy
     where SumAccount3 is not null)

select * from cter
WHERE AccountNumber = 'K07_1010'
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Giorgi, thank you very much for your answer. I have done some testing and it seems to work fine apart from the obvious restirction for account K07_1010. I will check some more tomorrow without that restriction (and also add the original mapping K07_1010 to K07_1010 seems to be missing too). But these are just minor things. The real important thing is that you've been able to crack it and that is absolutely splendid. Thank you. So, I'll do some more checking and once verified mark it as answered.

Comment: after several checks I can say that it is working as expected. Thanks again!